# Attach material.io menu component to all elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design

I'm trying to figure out a way to attach the material.io menu across a webpage that has multiple menus. I tried to use jQuery each function but obviously the code does not work. Here is the original code suggested by material.io (works for one menu only)

```
var menu_element = document.querySelector('.obox-admin-menu') !== null;
if (menu_element) {
    var menuEl = document.querySelector('.obox-admin-menu');
    var menu = new mdc.menu.MDCMenu(menuEl);
    var menuButtonEl = document.querySelector('.obox-admin-menu-btn');
    menuButtonEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
        menu.open = !menu.open;
    });
}
```

And here is my attempt with jQuery but it failed.

```
$( '.mdc-menu-anchor' ).each(function() {
    var menuEl = $( this ).find('.obox-admin-menu');
    var menu = new mdc.menu.MDCMenu(menuEl);
    var menuButtonEl = $( this ).find('.obox-admin-menu-btn');
    $( document ).on( 'click', menuButtonEl, 'click', function() {
        menu.open = !menu.open;
    });
});
```

What I'm doing wrong here? I'm trying to make menu trigger for multiple elements with same class and markup, I thought that could be possible with a loop but I'm new to javascript.

**UPDATE**

based on comment by connexo I have now added the functionality I am looking for with this (hope this code approach is fine)

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll( '.mdc-menu-anchor' );
Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, function (item) {
    var menuEl = item.querySelector('.obox-admin-menu');
    let menu = new mdc.menu.MDCMenu(menuEl);
    let menuButtonEl = item.querySelector('.obox-admin-menu-btn');
    menuButtonEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
        menu.open = !menu.open;
    });
});
```

Comment: You are passing a jQuery element to material whereas it expects to get a native DOMElement. Use `var menuEl = $( this ).find('.obox-admin-menu')[0];`to get the DOMElement from jQuery. Also, **why are you complicating stuff by using jQuery**?

Comment: I do not know how to loop through elements with pure javascript that's why I am using jquery.

Comment: Then why not educate yourself on that? https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: Thanks!! :) Turns out it was not as bad as i thought. i edited question, please check.

Comment: Replace `var menuButtonEl ` by `let menuButtonEl` in your code, otherwise all event listeners will share the last occurrence of `item.querySelector('.obox-admin-menu-btn')`.

Comment: Also replace `var menu = new mdc.menu.MDCMenu(menuEl);` by `let menu = new mdc.menu.MDCMenu(menuEl);`

Comment: Upvoted your question for willingness and ability to read documentation and learn.